# Comment Evaluator 5000 error when logging in on a different device

Tags: bug, comment-evaluator-5000

So I received an email inviting me to participate in the comment evaluator 5000 last week. I logged in at home and did some evaluating. Everything worked fine.

Now when I try to log in from a different device, a separate window opens with

> Cannot GET /undefined&client_id=13171&state=3

This other device is a Windows 10 Desktop PC using Firefox 62.0.2. All relevant addons are disabled for the comment evaluator.

Comment: That is odd. I was able to log in to the tool on two different devices myself, one of which was with that version of Firefox.